# Use Mojolicious action as title in template

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I'm trying to make the default "title" variable in stash be set to the English version of the action name. For example:

```
sub customer_orders {
    ...
}
```

Would have:

```
title => 'Customer Orders',
```

Available in the stash for the templates to use. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `$c->action` is available in Mojolicious templates as `$action`. So you can just do this:

```
<title><%= title || action_to_title($action) %>
```

This way other templates can override the title like so:

```
% title 'My Override Title'
```

And you can add the `action_to_title` helper to prepare the action for a title if `title` is not set.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the subroutine name via caller:

`my $sub_name = (caller(0))[3];`.

Judging from your output, you may want to also upcase it and replace _ with whitespace

`$sub_name =~ s /_/ /g;`

I would upcase like this:
`my $title = join(' ', map{ ucfirst lc }split(' ', $sub_name) );`

Answer (score 0):

You can put title into layout template

```perl
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= content 'title' %></title>
    <style>
      label.field-with-error { color: #FF4C4D }
      input.field-with-error { background-color: #FF4C4D }
      .error_msg { color: #FF4C4D }
    </style>
    %= content 'styles';
  </head>
  <body>

%= include 'basic/menu'
%= include 'basic/error_messages'
%= content
%= content_for 'include_js'
</body>
</html>
```

Then at your template fill it with [`content`](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojolicious/Plugin/DefaultHelpers#content) (read also about `content_for`, `content_with`)

```perl
% content_with title => "$title_schet за $title_date";
% content_for styles => '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/report.css">';

<form>
  ...
</form>
```